# Generate unique id for h:dataTable in the loop

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am using JSF 2.0. When I am trying to use a variable in the 'id' attribute of the h:dataTable its not taking that variable value.

I have h:dataTable inside ui:repeat with id values as index of ui:repeat as mentioned below.

```
    <ui:repeat var="planMap" value="#{planAccountMap.entrySet().toArray()}" varStatus="planMapStatus">

    <h:dataTable id="planTable#{planMapStatus.index}" value="#{planMap.value}" var="accountList">
```

Does any one know whether we can have dynamic id generated for h:dataTable in loop?

I have a Java script which is making use of table id, but as I am not able to have the unique id for each table in the loop, its breaking.

Comment: Components will emit a client identifier according to the rules specified by [UIComponent.getClientId](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29)

Comment: Thanks all for your research and response. I have solved this problem by using datatable inside datatable as below. `<h:dataTable id="outerTable" value="#{planAccountMap.entrySet().toArray()}" var="planMap"> <h:dataTable id="planTable" value="#{planMap.value}" var="accountList"> ` . By this I am getting unique id as  `outerTable:0:planTable`, `outerTable:1:planTable`...This even extend the unique id to each element in datatable as `outerTable:1:planTable:1:columnid` , `outerTable:0:planTable:0:columnid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solve by using datatable inside datatable. Second datatable is kept inside the column of the first datatable as below.

```
<h:dataTable id="outerTable" value="#{planAccountMap.entrySet().toArray()}" var="planMap" width="100%">
  <h:column> 
  <h:dataTable id="planTable" value="#{planMap.value}" var="accountList"
  headerClass="tablehead" 
  rowClasses="'',altrowcoloropt1"
  first="0">
    <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Date" />
    </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{accountList.date}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header" >
        <h:outputText value="Account Name" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{accountList.accountName}"/>
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

By this you would get unique id as `outerTable:0:planTable`, `outerTable:1:planTable`.This even extend the unique id to each element in datatable as `outerTable:1:planTable:1:columnid` , `outerTable:0:planTable:0:columnid`

Answer (score 0):

Any component inside of a repeatable component will always have a dynamic client id.  You cannot do this.

Perhaps instead you can assign a unique style class to the dataTable component and use a jQuery selector to return an array of all the dataTable objects in the `ui:repeat`.

```
jQuery('.SomeClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

I do some thing very similar to you. i have a UI:repeat inside a datatable column. tbh, if you check in fire bug, your datatable id would be unique as you put it inside a ui:repaet.

```
planMap:0:yourdatatableID
```

Comment: This could be one solution, but in my case I have multiple columns with different formatting so I would prefer to use datatable only.Now I am using datatable inside a datatable which worked perfectly.